# Pass 1 parameter in oAuth to access them after redirect URI was called

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0

I have configured a oAuth 2.0 authentication flow for my Angular singlePage website:

1. User opens my Login page depending on his language:
   `example.com/en-GB` or `example.com/de-DE`
2. After clicking on a login Btn he get's redirected to the issuer page where he can login with his email and password.
3. The issuer page then redirects him to example.com/welcome

My problem is now, how to access the info about the user language once he got redirected from my welcome component. How do I know, if he came from `en-GB` od `de-DE`) and if I should display the english or the german version of example.com/welcome. Can I pass the parameter in the redirect URI, I tried but it didn't work?

I also tried taking the queryParam from the route in my login Component in step 1 and then put the value into a `Service`. That's usually how I pass data between components. But after the redirect, when the welcome component gets opened, the value is always null. I tried doing it with BehaviorSubject with a starting value of null.

Then I tried passing the value into my authConfig by using `customQueryParams` or `customTokenParameters`, but I don't know how to access these params from my welcome component once the redirect happend. They are not included in the identityClaims that I receive after the redirect.:

```
let authConfig: AuthConfig = {
      issuer: 'myIssuer.com',
      redirectUri: 'example.com/welcome',
      clientId: ...,
      scope: '...',
      responseType: '...',
      customQueryParams: {
        'locale': 'de_DE'
      },
      customTokenParameters: ["de-DE"],
      dummyClientSecret: ...
    };
```

Does anyone know the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OAuth2, you can use the `state` parameter to pass arbitrary data. The value passed here should get sent back to you verbatim.

Comment: Ok this seems right, thank you! But where do I set the state parameter in Angular?
I'm defining my authConfig like this: `authConfig: AuthConfig = {  issuer: '...', redirectUri: '...', state: 'myParam'(??) }` but the class AuthConfig doesn't have a parameter 'state', so I can't put it there... 
This is the import I'm using:
`import { AuthConfig } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';`

Comment: sorry, I commented a bit too quick, after trying it myself I found it out: In `this.oauthService.initImplicitFlow("<myStateParam>");` I can pass the state in and with `console.log("Passed around state: ", this.oauthService.state)` I can access it in my /welcome component.

Comment: @bwx--2 you might be interested to know that implicit flow is deprecated and considered insecure these days! Just a FYI